# "How to create a stand alone office Add-in install able on Mac" which I can distribute as a single file to the users

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in, office-addins, word-addins

"How to create a stand alone office Add-in install able on Mac" which I can distribute as a single file to the users.  ? without using office 365 . I referred to the below link but i didn't get solution.

1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish
2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store

Comment: @Cindy Meister is there any other reference that I need to refer for the above question.

Comment: I think the only possibility would be VBA code in a Word template. Although how well that works would depend, I believe, on the version of Office/Word (Mac has had its ups and downs with supporting VBA.) None of the other possibilities are "a single file".

Comment: @CindyMeister Then can you please suggest how to package and publish to distribute javaScript MS Word add-in project to a Mac user